# Problem with sending commands to mikrotik through telnet using expect script

Tags: expect, mikrotik

my task is to create automatic script, which send commands to mikrotik router through telnet. I am trying to create "expect" script.

But I got stuck at command sending part. Standalone login works well (first code), but when i add another command (second code), console gets stuck at password (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYFgL.jpg) for a few seconds and then i get output in picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJwgt.jpg

First code for login to router. This one works great.

```
spawn telnet "12.12.13.44";
expect "Login: ";
send "admin\r";
expect "password: ";
send "admin\r";
interact;
```

and here is same code after adding the command, i like to send

```
spawn telnet "12.12.13.44";
expect "Login: ";
send "admin\r";
expect "password: ";
send "admin\r";
expect "> ";
send "ip firewall filter add chain=forward src-address=34.54.32.33 action=log\r";
exit;
```

I got the same output when using script without expect, which i tried before "expect"

```
(
echo open "12.12.13.44"
sleep 2
echo "admin"
sleep 2
echo "admin"
sleep 2
echo "ip firewall filter add chain=forward src-address=34.54.32.33 action=log"
sleep 2
echo "exit"
) | telnet
```

PS. I am using Debian version 8 and RouterOS 6.34.4

PPS. Previously mentionet devices are for uploading final solution, I have another router and computer(Ubuntu 18.10 and RouterOS 6.44.1), where i try my scripts and the output, whitch I showed in picture, apears in both of my routers and computers.

I will be grateful for any advice with my problem.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for providing a clear question and showing what you tried!

Comment: RouterOS 6.34 is way too old; upgrade your mikrotik device and try again, maybe they fixed something.

Comment: Thank you for response. I updated RouterOS to 6.44.1, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution at: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Console_login_process#FAQ.
The problematic output disappeared after I added "+t" after login name.